# Can anyone help identifying this lens?

Tags: lens, nikon

I bought a Nikon FG today, with 2 lenses and a load of accessories.
One of the two lenses is kind of a mystery, as there's no manufacturer name on it.
I'm trying to figure out who's the manufacturer, the year of production, and the model.
I can only say that is a 28-85mm with macro, Nikon F mount, 62mm diameter, multy-coated. On the front it also says CCT and CPC. And then Auto Zoom (?).
On the side it says Made in Korea.
This is a link to a video where I just show the lens: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E_-vEnFKV3Y

Comment: I think "CPC" is _Combined Products Corporation_, a former Pentax subsidiary which made lower-cost closed-circuit television lenses (that's the CCT). I had no idea that these came in F mount, though.

Comment: @mattdm lots of special purpose industrial or scientific lenses and cameras use the F mount as a sort of convention. The C mount is more common with CCTV lenses though due to the use of smaller sensors.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a Cosmicar (Pentax subsidiary) lens, which is a basically Pentax lens without the Super Multi-Coating. While the subsidiary was primarily aimed at the CCT lens market, they did make a few different lenses on the K-mount and also some others such as the Nikon F-Mount and Yashica apparently.

A little, very little, history here:

http://kmp.bdimitrov.de/technology/non-SMC.html